# Cannot load a vue-component in blade file on Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I was able to load vue components in earlier versions of laravel. What I did was:

on app.js inside resources/app.js
I defined the component as below:

```js
Vue.component('upload-menu', require('./components/UploadMenu.vue').default);
```

After that in my blade file I was able to use it as follows:

```
    <div id="app">
        <upload-menu></upload-menu>
    </div>
```

But now the method doesn't seems to be not working on laravel 8.

Please help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... any error ? your getting?

Comment: try Vue.component('uploadMenu', ...), note to use camel case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the error ?!
Anyway, try this way in your `app.js`:

```
import componentName from "path/to/component.vue";

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        componentName
    },
});
```

Share the error you get.
Helps to solve your problem, though.